# How to run a python or .exe file in html page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I tried running my game on a html website, but it didn't work.
can i use html or css or javascript to open and application or .exe

i tried using iframe but it just shows me the parent directory [This is the image i receive] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUChj.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUChj.png)
i also tried the anchor function in html it didnt work either

Comment: Would you run an exe provided by an arbitrary web page?

Comment: The security hole if this would be possible would be insane.

Answer (score 3):

Recently thanks yo [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) is possible to run a python script within a HTML page in the new `<py-script>` tag, by example

```
 <py-script>
   from datetime import datetime
   now = datetime.now()
   now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
 </py-script>
```

You can see the Python source code within the `<py-script>` and `</py-script>` tags that go within the `<body>` of a `<html>` tag.
Here it is a fully working example, click on "full page" to see the output in the html page, that should be like

```
Hello world!
This is the current date and time, as computed by Python:
11/04/2022, 21:52:53
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <title>PyScript Hello World</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />

    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello world! <br>
    This is the current date and time, as computed by Python:
    <py-script>
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The magic happens thanks to Pyscript Web Assembly (WASM) Python interpreter called [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/), that is automatically loaded when injecting in the page a `<script>` tag that will load PyScript, parse the `<py-script>` tag and run the Python code right in the page!

```
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js">
```

It is worth to note that a lot of Python pip packages can be loaded in the page as well thanks to [micropip](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/micropip-api.html) that will work in the same way of Pypi [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), but in the html page, and thanks to PyScript engine it only needs to write a new `<py-config>` tag, having the packages to install:

```
<py-config>
    packages = [
      "matplotlib"
    ]
</py-config>
```

A good example is running the popular scientific visualization library [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) straight in the browser with that approach. Working example [here](https://pyscript.net/examples/matplotlib.html).

Answer (score 0):

**No, you cannot use HTML, CSS, or JavaScript to open an application or .exe file**

If it is python you would have to serve html files / http responses after making a http server via flask, django or the very basic ones. It is not such a simple thing as just iframing a python file or a packaged exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CPython to compile your Python script to a WebAssembly module (WASM)](https://pythondev.readthedocs.io/wasm.html#cpython-on-webassembly). Then you can load the WASM module in your HTML page and run it by calling it from JavaScript.